Upgraded from 23.04 to 24.04 and my laptop now boots into UEFI only
I upgraded from 23.04 to 24.04 using the GUI.
In the middle the text became garbled and then I was prompted to choose an option.

unfortunately, I couldn't tell what it says but I couldn't proceed without choosing an option so I chose one. It then immediately prompted a restart dialog.
Now it only boots into UEFI. I checked the Boot Sequence and it says Ubuntu at the top. Does anyone know how I could fix this?
edit: The laptop is a dell latitude.

FYI: Ubuntu 23.04 had one QA & CI tested upgrade path, and that was to the next release being Ubuntu 23.10. For best results you should use the fully supported & Quality Assurance tested upgrade path, and not force alternate upgrades.

I just followed what the instructions told me. The website says I go to Software Updates and the update it told me to get was 24.04. edit: I used the GUI entirely. I wasn't aware this was an alternate path.

Instructions for upgrades to 24.04 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades) don't mention 23.04 as its not a supported upgrade path. The instructions for 23.04 upgrades exist only at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades which isn't the upgrade path you accepted (you missed it most likely).  You can always re-install; non-destructive re-install maybe possible too, but regardless I'd ensure your backups are all good first, and stick to intended & supported upgrade paths in future.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-release-notes/39890

thanks for the comment. I'm not a very technical user, so I just followed the GUI. The top result on Google is this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start. Clearly this wasn't a good tutorial. For future reference, what keywords should I search for when upgrading?

Assuming the current installation cannot be fixed, on non-destructive reinstalls, I have gotten a Live USB with an Ubuntu 24.04 image in it. Is it possible to install while keeping your home directory? I saw this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation, but the 24.04 installer does not match the options. I instead see "How do you want to install Ubuntu? - alongside 23.10 (unless this is mislabeled, maybe the GUI tried installing 23.10 before the failing to reach GRUB on the next reboot); - erase disk; - manual installation."
